# Obtain the coordinates of the intersection of a line and anything iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, coordinates

i wanna create a dynamic graph by myself.
but my biggest problem is how can i get coordinates of the intersection of a line and my graph (suppose just a line)?

something like Stock App in iPhone,In this app, if you look at the chart,when you move the finger on the screen you will see coordinates of the intersection of the line and the graph.

thanks for any help
and sorry for my english :)

Comment: are you going to draw the graph by youself (i.e. draw axis, lines, etc)?

Comment: Well, yes i created a graph, this my graph:http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/21/iossimulatorscreenshoto.png/, but i cant create that red line to get coordinate of intersection

Answer (score 0):

To use the same example as in your question, to do something similar to the Stocks App on iPhone on this question, it is very easy:

- when the user touches the view, you get the coordinate of the touch on your view (`CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:yourView]`)
- then convert this point in view coordinates in a point on your graph: you probably know where the point representing abscissa X=0 of your graph is drawn, and where the point representing abscissa X=XMax is drawn too, so with simple maths you can determine at which abscissa your X position of your touch corresponds
- Then if you have the abscissa X corresponding to the point of your touch, you have everything (the Y on your curve that correspond to this X is given by the dataSource of your graph)

---

So imagine you draw some function `y=sin(x)` on your graph, and because your Y axis is say 20 points wide to let you draw the Y-axis labels, the point representing X=0 is drawn at `x=20pt` on your UIView. And imagine your X-axis goes from 0 to 10, and your point representing X=10 is drawn say at `x=300pt` on your view.

Then when the user taps at a point on your view whose x coordinate is `x=140pt`, then it is easy to compute that it corresponds to the coordinate X=5 on your graph (`(x-20)/(300-20)*Xmax = 120/240*10 = 5`, simple rule of three). So the user tapped at a point that corresponds to X=5, and on the curve the point with `X=5` has `Y=sin(5)` because your curve is `y=sin(x)`.

Comment: thanks, you right i used your answer already, and i can get my graph data with this solution, but my goal is to obtain values ​​between two points, if you look at : http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/21/iossimulatorscreenshoto.png/, you'll see i want to determinate value continuous numbers like 1.34, not 1, and number "1" is in my array not 1.34 .... and i think the best way is  Obtain the coordinates of the intersection of a line and graph.

Comment: Then once you have the X in your graph coordinates corresponding to the point touched (say X=1.34), search in your dataSource the X value before this one and the X value after this one, and do a simple linear interpolation. So if you touch at a point that has X=1.34 in your graph coordinates but you have points for X=X1 before and X=X2 after, simply compute `Y = Y1 + (X-X1)*(Y2-Y1)/(X2-X1)`.

Comment: this is a good solution too, but i used it already again, and problem with this solution is takes a few time to search in my database, so when you move you finger quickly (not really fast) cant see on time data and why i told the best way to terminate is get the coordinates of the intersection..., thanks again you are smart

Comment: Then you should cache the X values you fetch from your database into some memory storage for that purpose. A list of X values (and possibly Y values if needed) for one graph is really light to store in memory and will improve your performance.

Comment: _I also note that you are new to SO, so if my answer helped you don't forget to upvote it, and when your problem is solved to accept it, so let other users know which solution was more useful and when your problem is solved._

Comment: thanks but when i pressed the vote up button, says "vote up requires 15 reputation "

Answer (score 0):

Just from the top of my head, in naive ignorance of how graph showing programs usually do this (ie some kind of graph "best practice"):

Supposing your graph is made up of a number of (linear) lines, described by the normal line equation y = kx+m, I suppose you would have to solve the equations for when your reference line (let's call it refline) has the same x and y coordinates as the lines that make up the graph.

I.e., if your graph is one line, described by y = 2*x+100 (this is a super IT stock from 1999!), and your refline is currently at y = 120, I guess you would have to solve the equation system 120 = 2*x + 100 to get the x for where refline and the graph intersect.

Answer (score 0):

Guess you can get line to line intersection coordinate using linear algebra skills, for example what wikipedia knows about that: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line-line_intersection